# How to find the Transfer Function of this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, transfer-function, bode-plot

I am trying to find the transfer function of this circuit, but I can't find how. Does anyone have a clue?

[image: Proteus circuit]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to calculate the impedance of the circuit by calculating the sum of both of the resistor in parallel R5 and R6 and then combine it with the impedance of R7 and C4 , then doing the relation between Vin and Vout but I'm not sure of my result

Comment: What do you mean by "impedance of the circuit"? Are you talking about the equivalent Thevenin impedance? If so, between which nodes?

Comment: I am considering it a non-inverting amplifier with Z1 which is equivalent to the sum of R5 and R6 in parallel and Z2 which is equivalent to the impedance of R7 and C4
http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/opampkeisan.htm

Comment: Where's the input and where's the output? Show your calculations within your question and kindly explain what state you considered the switch was in. Edit your question; don't answer in comments please.

Comment: @Thefrenchy2706 Do you really see "the sum of R5 and R6 in parallel and Z2" ? Please, clarify.

Comment: if you represent the R7//C4 as an impedance Z1, R5//R6 as Z2, you would know easily it is a voltage divider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might find what you are looking for in this book: https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf

It is a reference guide that is invaluable for opamp design. Around the page 400, you might find what you look for!

Answer (score 7):

You can easily determine the transfer function of this circuit by considering a simple \$RC\$ low-pass filter followed by a non-inverting structure described in this Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications). Because the op-amp does not load the low-pass filter, you can cascade the two transfer functions conveniently:

[image]

The final expression shows the presence of a dc gain determined when \$s=0\$, one zero and two poles. The magnitude and phase plots between the three possible expressions are identical.

Comment: There is a small typo. You have C1 instead of C3 on the circuit diagram. But nevertheless excellent answer.

Comment: @VerbalKint Could you explain more about your comment surrounding the fact that since the Low Pass Filter is not loaded by the OP AMP, that allows you to proceed with cascading the transfer functions?

Comment: @RogerDodger If an opamp input were a load, then it's loading would have to be accounted for in the filter leading up to it, since that loading would alter the filter. But an opamp, fortunately, doesn't (with some thought, anyway) present an appreciable load on preceding filters. And it's output can usually drive the next one, readily. That's what allows the simpler algebra when cascading.

Comment: *G36*, merci for pointing this out, just corrected the picture. @RogerDodger, *periblepsis* gave you the right explanation why you could treat the front-end filter separately from the op-amp. If, instead, you want to consider \$R_{in}\$, the resistance seen at the (+) pin, then the dc gain and the first pole position would be slightly affected.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

We know, using the voltage divider formula, that we can write:

- $$\text{V}_+=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\tag1$$
- $$\text{V}_-=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{V}_\text{o}\tag2$$

When using an ideal OPAMP, we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{V}_\text{o}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\mathscr{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}\tag4$$

---

Applying this to your circuit we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_3}\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_7\cdot\frac{1\displaystyle}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_7+\frac{1\displaystyle}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4}}
\right)}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6}\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_7\cdot\frac{1\displaystyle}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_7+\frac{1\displaystyle}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4}}
+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_3}\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_3}\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_7}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4\text{R}_7+1}
\right)}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6}\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_7}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4\text{R}_7+1}
+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_3}\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_7}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4\text{R}_7+1}
}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6}\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{sC}_3\text{R}_7}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4\text{R}_7+1}
+1\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_7\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4\text{R}_7+1}
}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{sC}_3\text{R}_7}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4\text{R}_7+1}
+1\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\left(\text{sC}_4\text{R}_7+1\right)+\text{R}_7\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\left(\text{sC}_3\text{R}_7+\text{sC}_4\text{R}_7+1\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\left(\text{sC}_4\text{R}_7+1\right)+\text{R}_7\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\left(\text{sR}_7\left(\text{C}_3+\text{C}_4\right)+1\right)}
\end{split}\tag5
\end{equation}

So, the amplitude of this transfer function is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|&=\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_4\text{R}_7+1\right)+\text{R}_7\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\left(\text{j}\omega\text{R}_7\left(\text{C}_3+\text{C}_4\right)+1\right)}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{j}\omega\text{C}_4\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\text{R}_7+\text{R}_5\text{R}_6+\text{R}_7\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\text{j}\omega\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\text{R}_7\left(\text{C}_3+\text{C}_4\right)+\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\text{R}_5\text{R}_6+\text{R}_7\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{C}_4\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\text{R}_7\right)^2}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\text{R}_7\left(\text{C}_3+\text{C}_4\right)\right)^2}}
\end{split}\tag6
\end{equation}

And the argument is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)&=\arg\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_4\text{R}_7+1\right)+\text{R}_7\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\left(\text{j}\omega\text{R}_7\left(\text{C}_3+\text{C}_4\right)+1\right)}\right)\\
\\
&=\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}_4\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\text{R}_7}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6+\text{R}_7\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\text{R}_7\left(\text{C}_3+\text{C}_4\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6}\right)\\
\\
&=\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}_4\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\text{R}_7}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{R}_6+\text{R}_7\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)}\right)-\arctan\left(\omega\text{R}_7\left(\text{C}_3+\text{C}_4\right)\right)
\end{split}\tag7
\end{equation}

Using your values, we get:

- $$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\sqrt{730458729\omega^2+749664400000000000000}}{11 \sqrt{19882681  \omega  ^2+1000000000000000000}}\tag8$$
- $$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{27027\omega}{27380000000}\right)- \arctan\left(\frac{4459\omega}{1000000000}\right)\tag9$$

Comment: Hello Jan, I like mathematical treatment when needed but here you have an unloaded low-pass filter followed by a non-inverting op-amp featuring a pole : ) A simple inspection of the circuit would give the transfer function immediately. Cheers!